# Angular - dynamically inject content to <ng-content> component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have composition of components

ComponentA
`<div class="CA"><ng-content></ng-content></div>`

ComponentB
`<div class="CB"><ng-content></ng-content></div>`

And in parent I want to use them like this:

```
<component-a>
    <component-b>
        // I want something here
        <div>some-content injected from parent<div/>
    </component-b>
</component-a>
```

So, my components are designed to be composable and parent requires access to all components from it's scope - without shadowing api.

What I want to do is also affect children of `component-b` from `component-a`. I want to access `I want something here` from `ComponentA.component.ts` and inject something there.

Real life example:

```
<app-input-with-buttons (onButtonClick)="someCallback()">
    <app-input [validationMessage]="someValidation$ | async">
        <input ngModel />
    </app-input>
</app-input-with-buttons>
```

I need `InputWithButtonsComponent` to inject HTML to `InputComponent` children.

I know it "too React way", but this approach allows me to limit components to single responsibility, allowing form component to control each step of form control.

Is it possible to access many nesting levels of `ng-content` in Angular? Also, are there better architecture patterns for solutions like this?